# Convert To (48 bits, Little Endian)

Tags: c#, type-conversion, endianness

I am communicating with a card via UDP, sending messages and receiving responses with the data I want!
I have a small problem in the conversion of these two parameters:
[Paremeters Argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsc5K.jpg)

When I send the command 0x22 to read the firmware version I get this response (index 3,4,5) but they are not in yymmdd format given the results I got 38 and 33 ...
[0x22 Reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BdKN.jpg)

When I send the command 0x21 to read the UI version
i get this result, how i can convert it to 48 bit little endian
[0x21 Réponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIPAM.jpg)

Comment: `int serialNumber = byte1 + 256 * byte2 + (256*256 * byte3) + ... + (256*256*256*256*256 * byte6)`

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder?view=net-5.0   -- for standard Endianess conversion.

Comment: Error Complitor L'opération engendre un dépassement de capacité au moment de la compilation dans le mode check @xanatos

Comment: @QuatreHuit Ah right... 48 bits... You need 64 bits... `long serialNumber = byte1 + 256L * byte2 + (256L*256L * byte3) + ... + (256L*256L*256L*256L*256L * byte6)`. Use a `long` and put a L after each 256, so that the operations are done in `long`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is something like:

```
long serialNumber = byte1 + (256L * byte2) + (256L*256L * byte3) + ... + (256L*256L*256L*256L*256L * byte6)
```

Note that it is surely possible to do it with bit-shifting:

```
long serialNumber = ((long)byte1) | ((long)byte2 << 8) | ((long)byte3 << 16) | ... | ((long)byte6 << 40)
```

Both are based on how a little-endian number is represented in memory.